# Creating a 2-dimensional table with div without the table tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to make a table using the div tag without a table tag using javascript. I did it myself using div but I can't generate a table with js. I want the sequence number inside the table cells.What kind of path can I follow?

The piece of code I use is as follows

```js
var count=1;
var table=document.createElement("table");
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
var tr=document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(tr);
for(var j=0;j<8;j++){
    var td=document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML=count++;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    }  
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("display").appendChild(table);
```

```css
label{
                display: block;
            }
            table,td{
                border:1px solid grey;
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="display"></div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want similar code but using `div` elements instead of `table/tr/td` elements?

Comment: @Benny Yes that would be great. Very similar to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `table, tr and td` tags into `div` and then you can use `display` property with `table, table-row and table-cell`..

See the Snippet below:

```js
var count=1;
var table=document.createElement("div");
table.className = "table";

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
var tr=document.createElement("div");
tr.className = "row";
table.appendChild(tr);
for(var j=0;j<8;j++){
    var td=document.createElement("div");
    td.className = "cell";
    td.innerHTML=count++;
    td.addEventListener("click", function(_event){
      console.log(_event.target.innerHTML);
    });
    tr.appendChild(td);
    }  
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("display").appendChild(table);
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
div, span{
    border:1px solid grey;
}
div#display{
  width: 186px;
}
div.table{
  display:table;
  padding:2px;
  width: 180px;
}
div.row{
  display:table-row;
}
div.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="display"></div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I am grateful for your answer. It solved the first part of my problem. Thanks to your help, I want to get the numerical value of that cell when I click on the cells while doing my own work. Should I use span class for this? I would be very happy if you helped with that.

Comment: Hey @sadikkaplan, I have added click event.. Please run the Snippet code

Comment: Dude you really helped a lot. I thank you very much. You are a good developer.